Shadcn initialization issue with Vite React
I'm installing shadcn in a React application with Vite, but when following the steps in their documentation, the components are placed inside the @ directory, and I can't use them.
One thing I've noticed is that when creating the React project, I have three TypeScript configuration files: tsconfig.json, tsconfig.app.json, and tsconfig.node.json.
Project structure:
--| @
----| components
------| ui
--| tailwind.config.js
--| src
----| App.tsx
I want the shadcn library components to be placed inside the src directory.

They added explanation to the installation docs for Vite.
But, this works only with typescript.
You need to edit both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json files.
and because you use vite that uses ES modules, your vite.config should have this (I am telling it to install components in ./app/..., you can change this to whatever, usually .src/ folder):
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

export default defineConfig({
  /.../
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), "./app"),
    },
  },
});

